# Showing a dialog multiple times causes Memory Leak?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have buttons in a list, each with the same handler, when anyone is pressed, I:

- add an event to the bloc
- bloc calls service to make network call
- when network call is successful, bloc emits new state
- ui updates accordingly

All the above works normally when I press any of the buttons, but only for couple of times. After several presses, the app starts gradually hanging until it finally totally hangs, and I need to kill it and restart it.

I suspect there is a memory leak, but I don't how to find it if this was the case.

Here is the relevant code:

- step 1: press on delete

```
              child: GestureDetector(
                onTap: addressState.deletingAddress
                    ? null
                    : () async {
                        bool shouldDelete =
                            (await _showDeleteAddressDialog(address.title))!;
                        if (shouldDelete && mounted) {
                          context.read<AddressBloc>().add(
                                AddressEvent.deleteAddress(
                                  addressId: address.id,
                                  onError: (errorMessage) =>
                                      snackbars.showSnackBar(
                                    context: globalScaffoldKey.currentContext!,
                                    text: errorMessage,
                                  ),
                                ),
                              );
                        }
                      },
                child: Container(
                  color: Colors.transparent,
                  width: 80.sp,
                  height: 50.sp,
                ),
              ),
```

- step 2: The bloc handler is called

```
  Future<void> _handleLoadAddresses(_LoadAddresses event, Emitter emit) async {
    if (state.loadingAddresses) return;

    emit(state.copyWith(loadingAddresses: true));

    final Either<String, List<Address>> result =
        await _addressManagementService.getAllAddresses();

    result.fold(
      (errorMessage) {
        emit(
          state.copyWith(
            loadingAddresses: false,
            loadingAddressesErrorMessage: errorMessage,
          ),
        );
        event.onError?.call(errorMessage);
      },
      (addresses) => emit(
        state.copyWith(
          addresses: UnmodifiableListView(
            addresses,
          ),
          loadingAddresses: false,
          loadingAddressesErrorMessage: null,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

- step 3: network call

```
   Future<Either<String, void>> deleteAddress(int addressId) async {

      ...
        return ...
      ...
    } catch (e) {
      return ...
    }
  }
```

- And this is the dialog code:

```
  Future<bool?> _showDeleteAddressDialog(String addressTitle) async =>
      dialogs.showActionDialog(
        context: context,
    // ...
        onBarrierDismissed: (context) => GoRouter.of(context).pop(false),
        onRightButtonPressed: (context) => GoRouter.of(context).pop(true),
        onLeftButtonPressed: (context) => GoRouter.of(context).pop(false),
      );
```

where `showActionDialog` simply calls `showDialog`, the built-in flutter function

I tried looking at the devtools but couldn't see any crazy memory consumption, there were some jank frames but that is expected in debug mode.

### Update:

I re-looked into dev tools, appears that when pressing the delete button many times (i.e. opening the dialog and pressing it), after several times, I noticed that the GC entered a non-stopping loop of being triggered, and the memory consumption started increasing by around 8 MB and then decreasing by the same amount when the GC is triggered, and the `_List` and `_ListIterator` and `_WhereIterator`
were the most classes that took memory space, I don't know if these are related to the `bloc` handler of the delete event because there I use `List` and `where` to filter the list

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why this works, but after this change, the GC started triggering normally and the app didn't hang anymore as it did before:

I just changed the inlined list modification into an explicit for loop:

so I replaced

```
  Future<void> _handleLoadAddresses(_LoadAddresses event, Emitter emit) async {
    if (state.loadingAddresses) return;

    emit(state.copyWith(loadingAddresses: true));

    final Either<String, List<Address>> result =
        await _addressManagementService.getAllAddresses();

    result.fold(
      (errorMessage) {
        emit(
          state.copyWith(
            loadingAddresses: false,
            loadingAddressesErrorMessage: errorMessage,
          ),
        );
        event.onError?.call(errorMessage);
      },
      (addresses) => emit(
        state.copyWith(
          addresses: UnmodifiableListView(
            addresses,
          ),
          loadingAddresses: false,
          loadingAddressesErrorMessage: null,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

with

```
  Future<void> _handleDeleteAddress(_DeleteAddress event, Emitter emit) async {
    if (state.deletingAddress) return;

    emit(state.copyWith(deletingAddress: true));

    bool willSelectedAddressBeRemoved =
        state.selectedAddress?.id == event.addressId;

    final Either<String, void> result =
        await _addressManagementService.deleteAddress(event.addressId);

    await result.fold(
      (errorMessage) {
        emit(
          state.copyWith(
            deletingAddress: false,
            deletingAddressErrorMessage: errorMessage,
          ),
        );
        event.onError?.call(errorMessage);
      },
      (_) async {
        List<Address> updatedAddresses = [];
        for(Address address in state.addresses) {
          if(address.id != event.addressId) {
            updatedAddresses.add(address);
          }
        }
        emit(
          state.copyWith(
            selectedAddress:
                willSelectedAddressBeRemoved ? null : state.selectedAddress,
            addresses: UnmodifiableListView(
              updatedAddresses,
            ),
            deletingAddress: false,
            deletingAddressErrorMessage: null,
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
```

Update:
Just as insight to why I did this change and why I think it resolved the problem, I was seeing in the dart devtools during each time I press the button that was causing the leak, that there was a big increase in the number of classes related to lists and closures, and since the button was triggering change of bloc state by updating the state using a closure (using `map`) method, I got rid of the closure by making an explicit for loop and now pressing the button no matter how many times and how rapidly doesn't trigger crazy GC loops and the app does not hang anymore.

Happy to edit the answer if someone can confirm that this was not the cause of the leak or if the problem was something else at all.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).